# PhpSpreadsheet: Disable formatting on getValue() method

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm working with date and time cell values, and while the date values are working, time is proving to be a bit of a pain.

```
$value = $worksheet->getCell($cellPosition)->getValue();
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToTimestamp($value));
echo '<td>' . $date->format('i:s') . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

However, in this example: `$value` is: 0.375 instead of: 09:00, so the formatting fails.

How do I disable this default formatting of values?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for scripts to change the data type used for returning date values by calling the `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Functions::setReturnDateType($returnDateType)` method.

As `$returnDateType` use the constant `RETURNDATE_PHP_OBJECT`.

Then the date value returned to the calling script by any access to the Date and Time functions in Excel will be a `PHP DateTime object`

[Handling Date and Time Values](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/calculation-engine/#handling-date-and-time-values)

Comment: I tried some variations, but none worked. Do you have a code sample, in the context of the code I've used?

Comment: What returns this: `echo \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Functions::getReturnDateType();` ?

Comment: I get an error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Functions::getReturnDa‌​teType()